# What font is similar to Zapfino One but a bit more legible?

Tags: font-recommendation

I am looking for a font for my wedding invitation. I like [Zapfino One](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/zapfino/) but I think it is not readable enough for an invitation. Especially the letter "f" is very large. Is there any professional looking font which is similar to Zapfino One but a bit more readable for my purpose? If not are there any other suggestions?

For sake of completeness, here is a sample of Zapfino One:

[image: http://pbrd.co/123thhC]

Since I make the invitation with LaTeX (XeLaTeX) it would also be ok if you suggest a LaTeX metafont (which I could use with pdflatex).

I am also considering to make the menu-cards with Zapfino One, so it would be great if the font of the wedding invitation would fit to Zapfino One.

Comment: Are you using `pdfLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`? Because if you are using `XeLaTeX` (or `LuaLaTeX`), you can use any opentype or truetype font thanks to `fontspec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found some other fonts (all with Zapf in its name but I don't know if Herrman Zapf is the author of them)

### [Zapf Chancery Normal](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-zapf-chancery/)

[image: Chancery]

This font is also available for [pdflatex as metafont](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/zapfchan/).

### [Zapf Chance Italic](http://ttfonts.net/font/1389_ZapfChance.htm)

[image: Chance]

### [Zapf Calligraphic 801 Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/zapf-calligraphic-801/)

[image: Calligraphic]

### [Italianno](http://www.fontspace.com/typesetit/italianno)

Furthermore I have found another font called Italianno:

[image: Italianno]

Answer (score 4):

Out of the LaTeX metafonts on [this](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) page, I think the closest to Zaphino One would be Calligra

[**Calligra**](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligra/)

[image: Calligra metafont]

Ignoring the LaTeX metafont requirement, there is usually a section devoted to [wedding fonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Awedding/fonts/) at the larger font vendor websites. Lovers Pro has a similar style but has a little more flamboyance. Virtuosa Classic also looks similar to Zapfino One and is by the same author.

[**Lovers Pro**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/scholtz/lovers-pro/)

[image: Lovers Pro Font]

[**Virtuosa Classic**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/virtuosa-classic/)

[image: Virtuosa Classic Font]

Comment: LaTeX can handle OpenType fonts quite well today thanks to XeTeX and LuaTeX.